# Generating pdf in Angular 2

Tags: pdf, angular, pdf-generation

Me again with another Angular 2 question.

We are trying to generate a PDF file from a html source. I searched and searched trying to find an Angular 2 wrapper for the jsPdf or makePdf libraries, but I can't find any. Is there something I am missing? Is there a pure javascript way and is that good practice? Hope you guys can help.

Thanks in advance.

Francois

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing, some weeks ago. I decided to do the generating on server-side (Node.js in my case). However you can do it on client-side, with jsPDF, like you mentioned.

Don't need a wrapper, just include the script and then access jsPDF through the window object. Wrapper will make it easier to test though.

I don't remember exactly but I thought it was something like this:

```
var doc = new window.jsPDF();
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to hear! Thanks you for the answer! We will try and go the javascript route because unfortunately we are not allowed to use nodejs. Our only other solution is to generate the pdf using out java backend.

Comment: @UberSwyser You should take a look at JasperReports for generating pdf files in Java: http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate a bit on the window object?

Comment: what would you like to know? You can do console.log(window) to see whats allready in the window and if it contains jsPDF.

Comment: That worked perfectly! So by using the window object we were able to access the jsPdf api with all the functions needed! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am getting error :
Property 'jsPDF' does not exist on type 'Window' in my ts file

Answer (score 1):

PDF is a complex file format, there may be some pdf parsers/generators built with js, but they will be limited & slow, your best bet is to do something server side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Our only alternative is to use our Java backend, but due to time restraints we are trying to do it client side. All the data for the field bindings is already client side which makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```
  <button type="button" (click)="downloadPdf()" 
          class="button">download</button>
```

---

Component.ts:

```
  downloadPdf(){
  this.authService.downloadPdf().subscribe(data => {
  this.partnerDetails = data
  } ); }
```

---

routes.js:

```
router.get('/downloadPdf',partnerCntrl.downloadPdf);
```

---

partnercntrl:

```
module.exports.downloadPdf = function (req, res) {
     var fs = require('fs');
     var pdf = require('html-pdf');
     var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
     var options = { format: 'Letter' };
     pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
     console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
     });
```

Comment: U can keep the html file that u want to convert into pdf in var html = fs.readFileSync('YOUR HTML FILE PATH'')  and u can give the path to download your generated pdf in pdf.create(html, options).toFile('YOUR PDF FILE PATH TO BE SAVED', function(err, res) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);